# sorting and displaying image based on size

Tags: php, directory, image

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br>";
    echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" height=150px><br>';
}
?>
```

using that code, i am able to display all the images in the folder
i want to display only one that meets a size parameter, and if there are more ignore them
basically  want to display the one thats like a box

and alternatively i want to display only the first image of that foreach loop
and if there are no images display a default image

EDIT
so

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $info = getimagesize($filename);
    if ($info[0] == $info[1]) {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br>";
        echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" height=150px><br>';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

gives you an image if its a box, (thanks to schnaader)
right but images that come close to a box should be included too, how can that be sorted, 
meaning if the height divided by width gives more than 1

Comment: Please clarify your intention a little. What is the "size parameter" by which you want to filter the images? Is it the width and height in pixels, or the storage space required for the image in kilobytes? I assume the former since you want one that is "like a box", but does it need to be exactly square, or have a certain aspect ratio, or some other boxy criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display only the first image by using break:

```
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br>";
    echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" height=150px><br>';
    break;
}
```

For only printing the one that meets a specific size, use [getimagesize](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-get-image-size/) and compare the width/height with the one you want, so basically use the code above, but wrap an if around the lines inside the foreach loop. The following could work, but I haven't used PHP for long, so don't rely on it:

```
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $info = getimagesize($filename);
    if ($info[0] == $width_i_want) {
      if ($info[1] == $height_i_want) {
        echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "<br>";
        echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" height=150px><br>';
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

And if you want to get the square-sized image, use

```
if ($info[0] == $info[1]) {
  [...]
```

EDIT: To get the image which is closest to square-sized, try this:

```
$record_ratio = 0;
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $info = getimagesize($filename);
    $ratio = $info[0] / $info[1];
    if (abs(1 - $ratio) < abs(1 - $record_ratio)) {
      $record_ratio = $ratio;
      $record_filename = $filename;
    }
    if (record_ratio == 1) break;
}
if ($record_ratio > 0) {
  echo '<img src="'.$record_filename.'" height=150px><br>';
}
```

Variations of this can also give you the images sorted by ratio or images with a ratio between two values (for example 0.75 <= ratio <= 1.25).

Comment: great works, can i put a range to the square, such as if
the image is close to a square but is not ==